# Display rgb888 data on android device screen from the native code

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, android-ndk

Here is a problem which i think only a person who has worked thoroughly in android-ndk can answer.

**Problem:** I have written an application which reads an input file using a file explorer. And then when a **button Decode and Play** is pressed the application should decode the encoded input file and display it on the device screen. The problem here is the decoding is performed in a native code. The decoding is proper as i dumped it on sdcard and verified it using raw video player. The decoded frames are in RGB888 format and are of data type **unsigned char**. So if anyone knows how to display the data from the native code please provide some suggestions regarding the same.

**I tried:** first i returned the frame buffer to the function from where the native code was invoked, then i converted the frame buffer to char array and returned this array as a java object(i.e. jcharArray) to my activity. In my activity i converted the char array to int array and allocated this array to a bitmap using setpixels() function. And then using a canvas i drew this frame to the device screen. How ever the application crashed and the main thing is that the control doesnt seem to come back to the java activity each time a frame is decoded. Moreover even if this technique works the frames displayed will be so slow that it can never look like an video.

So i kindly request you people to provide suggestions and any techniques to do the same.
Thanks in advance... Waiting for a reply...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're doing most of the work in Java, and just want to pass up bitmap data from JNI to Java. (Alternatives include doing the drawing itself from the JNI side using OpenGL ES.) If this is the case, check out the [`<android/bitmap.h>`](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/include/android/bitmap.h) header, which will require you to link against the jnigraphics library (`-ljnigraphics`).

Basically, you do the following:

1. Create an `android.graphics.Bitmap` of the appropriate frame size and data type on the Java side, and pass it through to your JNI code
2. In the receiving JNI code, call `AndroidBitmap_lockPixels()`, copy the data into the resulting pointer using `memcpy()` or equivalent, unlock the bitmap with `AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels()`, and return to Java.
3. Back on the Java side, use the bitmap anywhere you otherwise would.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Ya this may help but i'm not able to understand the bitmap plasma example which uses the above technique. Can u please provide an example or a code snippet to illustrate the above? I'll surely accept your answer if you do so. But please dont provide link to bitmap plasma sample program.